# C program compatability with Linux/BSD, and different architectures

Tags: c, linux, unix

A book I am reading suggests compiling programs on the machines they are intended for to ensure there isn't any issues.  One of the big reasons I wanted to learn C is because it (can be) compatible with all operating systems. I am using this one on linux. If compiling the program on the intended machine(s) is not an option, is there a procedure that can be followed to ensure the program will run perfectly regardless of what version of linux/bsd it is run on? Like a crib sheet of compatible functions for different O/S as well as different architectures, and how to deal with each difference to ensure compatability?

Comment: More information on related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12338811/will-the-a-out-file-run-on-a-different-machine

Comment: Any reason why you can't run a VM? That won't solve your architecture bit, but at least you could test API compatibility with the OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use libraries intended to work cross platform.  If you do need to do anything that is platform dependent, you will have to write code that accounts for all architectures/platforms you want your application to run on.

Specific platforms will have `#define X` to determine if that's what the code runs on, so you can `#ifdef X` to check a specific platform and then write your code inside that statement, do the same for each bit of platform specific code.

Comment: "Use libraries intended to work cross platform" - how to know this? . "you will have to write code that accounts for all architectures/platforms you want your application to run on", procedure?

Comment: @user1166981 normally library documentation will tell what platforms it is compatible with.

Comment: And the architecture question?

Comment: @user1166981 architectures you normally use a specific compiler for, like if you compile to X86 you use a compiler that will compile to that, if you use ARM, same thing.  I'm sure there's also flags to check architectures, same as there is flags to check platforms

Answer (score 1):

You're confused between source compatibility and binary compatibility. Binaries are most definitely not portable, and that's got nothing to do with the programming language. A binary compiled on BSD will never run on linux, for example, since all the syscalls have different numbers and conventions.

The C code though should be portable and compatible with a wide variety of OSes, if written carefully. You just have to compile it separately on each platform you target.

Answer (score 0):

I would consult the following couple of links to get some basic information

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Standard_Base

http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/lsb

Answer (score 0):

the standard C is portable, but as with all languages, anything outside memory management and very basic libraries that the languages went out of their way to include will not be portable.

This problem is there even in Java, as suppose you want to do something that is seemingly portable (like setting color of the console window to green, or red) would not be possible.

Overall, example-book C tends to be very portable, or portable with very minor fixes (such as making explicit casting).