# When does C/C++ have to be compiled?

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction

This question assumes that the C/C++ code that is written is portable and does not use platform specific code.

I am beginning to learn C++ and how to compile code. I know that C was created to avoid assembly languages because programs would have to be rewritten for different  hardware configurations. I also know that C/C++ has to be recompiled for different computer configurations.

That made me wonder what constitutes a new configuration. I can download an executable file from the internet that works just fine, and the internet obviously does not know my hardware configuration. Does code have to be compiled for each different CPU? Does code compiled for one OS version work for another one? (Does Windows 7 code work for Windows 8 without a recompilation?)

In a nutshell, what conditions define a new configuration that has to be compiled for?

Comment: Generally there are two things you need to care about: CPU Architecture and ABI.

Comment: Does Windows 8 code work for Windows 7 without a recompilation? - Possibly.

Comment: @joschuck If you don't use platform-specific API's, yes it will run.

Comment: CPU families usually have a common core to their (assembly) language that they all share. So as long as your code is compiled for the correct general platform and OS, it should work.

Comment: Running compiled C code on a box, on which you did NOT do the compilation, is a recipe for disaster IMO.

Comment: @ChristopherHarris, and yet commercial software does exist and works well enough.

Comment: @StoryTeller So you are saying C is portable? I am not denying that commercial software written in C/C++ is available, but to say that "General platform and OS" should work.. means you suggest that different flavors or linux would run C/C++ code just fine in a production environment?

Comment: @ChristopherHarris, in what sense!? Using a standard compliant compiler to compile standard compliant code to a certain platform configuration, will make that code runable on that platform configuration, which may be on another box. And as long as you don't depend on platform specific functionality.. yes, it could run on different flavors of linux.

Comment: @remyabel: I think you meant homogeneous.

Comment: @remyabel: You can only edit comments for 5 minute after you post them. If you like, you can copy-and-paste your comment into a new one and delete the old one (and then I'll delete my comments).

Comment: A lot of hardware is homogeneous nowadays so it's not always necessary to compile a program, you can sometimes distribute binaries. But if you were to compile for completely different architectures, you would need a cross compiler or to distribute the source files so can it be compiled on the destination machine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Binary compatibility over what range of machines?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12338811/binary-compatibility-over-what-range-of-machines)

Comment: @sorush-r If the processor changes, the code will have to be recompiled.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I assume only operating system (in this case Win 7 and 8) are changed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

C and C++ are compiled programming languages. A [compiled language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiled_language) is a programming language whose implementations are typically compilers - translators which generate machine code from source code -, and not interpreters. Machine code is a set of instructions executed directly by a computer's processor. There is two things make programs incompatible with hardware/software combinations. Most important one in The Machine (Hardware) you are trying to run your binary on. For example you need to know that a program compiled on a 64-bit CPU, can not be run  on a 32-bit or ARM processor.

There are [dozens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CPU_architectures) of [computer architectures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_architecture) and sub-architectures. Major architectures are x86, x86_64 (amd64) and probably ARM. If you are using a language that it's code is going to be compiled to machine code, you will be able to distribute binary artifacts only on computers that have a CPU compatible with yours (Unless you are cross-compiling).

Hardware is not the only difference between platforms. Usually your code is meant to be handled by Operating System before meeting CPU. The part of operating system that do this job is called [application Binary Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface). You can't run an ELF binary compiled on Linux with Windows even if on same machine, because Win32 executables are different.

Comment: By the way, word size of a CPU is not the primary consideration.  The Intel, Freescale and ARM processor have different instruction sets.  An instruction on one is not compatible on the others.

Comment: @ThomasMathews even better the x86 instruction set has optional instructions, most x86 binaries contain multiple paths to use optional instructions when available and default to the slower core set otherwise. You can tell most compilers to assume that these instructions are present, resulting in smaller and sometimes faster binaries at the cost of being incompatible with other x86 CPUs.

Answer (score 10):

At a hardware level, a C program has to be compiled for each processor architecture. A code compiled for x86 will work on x86 processors, regardless of model or maker (intel/amd), but won't work on Itanium architectures for instance.

As for OS, if the program uses OS-specific libraries, it will work only on that OS. For instance, a program that uses `CreateFile` from Windows will work on Windows only. There are ways, like macros, in which a program can call a different function depending on what OS was compiled for. Even if a program calls only portable (ISO) functions, it still need to be recompiled for each OS (windows, linux, mac) because executable formats are different for each OS (linux uses ELF, windows uses PE).

Furthermore, for instance, when you deploy a library, for a specific OS and architecture, sometimes you need to have 2 compiled versions: a release and a debug version.

Compilers have optimization options for certain architectures, so you will obtain a program that can run on any x86 architecture, but is optimised for Intel Nehalem processors.

Sometimes, new processors introduce new hardware features that are transparent, that is the code does not need to be rewritten, but, in order for the program to benefit from them, the program must be recompiled with a new version of the compiler that can tap into these new features. An example of this was Pentium Pro who introduced new conditional move instructions (C code doesn't need to be rewritten, but the compiler need to be aware so that it generates these instructions).

Comment: Even if a C or C++ program does not use OS-specific libraries, it will often have to be linked with a platform-specific run-time library. So, for example, a "Hello, world!" app built for Windows can't be run on Linux, or vice versa, even if the hardware architecture is the same.

Comment: @KristopherJohnson It's not just the libraries.  The format of an executable is different on Linux and on Windows, so even if you don't use anything from the library (which means no input or output), you likely cannot run the executable.

Answer (score 5):

What makes you think that C or C++ *has* to be compiled? It just happens to be the traditional approach. There are, at least, three different ways C++ is executed:

1. Traditionally C and C++ are compiled to achieve maximum performance on a given system.
2. Some systems transform the code to an intermediate format which is then evaluated by a suitable virtual machine, e.g., [llvm](http://llvm.org/) does this. Obviously it assumes that llvm is installed on the machine executing it.
3. C and C++ can be interpreted. For example [cling](http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/cling) is a C++ interpreter.

The compilation step itself verifies that certain constraints are met before even considering to run the program, primarily to catch errors. Beyond catching errors, being able to determine prior to running what is being executed has some performance advantages. Compilation to the native instructions has several performance advantages:

1. The code can make informed decisions on the size of integers, support floating point units, required memory alignment, etc.
2. The native instructions are evaluated by the system's hardware which tends to be quite a bit more effective
3. When linking to libraries the entry points for the various functions can be determined at link time, possibly avoiding function call overheads.

The operating system per se generally don't really make much of a difference although the start and termination code to be executed for programs differs between different operating systems. Also, the available libraries and the APIs how to access common operations are different and sometimes require a different approach how to program your application effectively.

Comment: Valid points and definitely noteworthy, but doesn't quite answer his question.

Comment: The operating system _does_ make a difference if you use `new` or `delete`, or large parts of the standard library (like `std::cin` or `std::filebuf`).

Comment: And also, of course, the actual format of the executable varies.  If the code is fully compiled and linked (the usual case), Windows cannot load an executable in Linux format and vice versa (as far as I know---there are emulators under Linux which do support running Windows programs, but you need to run them under a special program).

Comment: Like @bolov said, this doesn't answer my question, but I did not previously know this. +1 for the interesting information.

Answer (score 2):

As Dietmar explained, it isn't even necessary for C++ to be
compiled (and there was once a group involved in trying to
standardize some "half-compiled" format for C, so that you could
download a program, and it would run on any Unix platform).  So
the ultimate answer is it has to be recompiled when the
implementation documentation says it has to be recompiled.
(This is known as binary compatibility, and most C++ compilers
document what is compatible, and what not.)

In practice, for most implementations:

- You will have to rebuild (compile and link) if you change
  architecture or the basic OS: code compiled for Linux generally
  won't run under Windows, or even under Solaris, and code 
  compiled for a Sparc won't run on an Intel architecture.
- You will often have to recompile if you want to take advantage
  of newer features.  If you want to run on older platforms, you
  may have to compile on them as well, or specify some sort of
  compatibility option to the compiler when you compile, so that
  the compiled code (and libraries) won't use any of the new
  features.  Thus, for example, by default, the most recent versions of VS
  use machine instructions which weren't present on older versions
  of Intel architectures (but which are significantly faster, at
  least where floating point is involved).  But they have options
  to tell the compiler not to use these instructions.

If you want to get an idea just how much things can vary, even
for the same architecture and the same OS, you might take a look
at the architecture dependent options for g++
(http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.3/gcc/i386-and-x86_002d64-Options.html#i386-and-x86_002d64-Options).
Not all of the options there will affect binary compatibility,
but a number of them do.
In particular, things like `-mfpmath`: if you use `-mfpmath=387`
(which I think is the default for g++), your program will run on
pretty much any Intel 32 bit architecture; if you use one of the
other options, it may not run on some of the older processors
(but it will run a lot faster on the new oned—and give
different results, because the characteristics of the floating
point processor are different).