# Getting the error: bash: (program): cannot execute binary file: Exec format error, on both 32-bit and 64-bit Windows

Tags: windows, bash, unix, executable, elf

There is a program developed for linguistic research (http://people.csail.mit.edu/mcollins/code.html). When I try to run the parser using Git bash terminal on Windows, I get the error:

```
bash: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error.
```

First, I assumed it's because of my 64-bit OS, since the file is 32-bit. So, I tried the program on a 32-bit system, but got the same message.

Any ideas on how to fix the issue?:

`file (program)` shows:

```
ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.2.5, with debug_info, not stripped
```

`uname -srv` for my 64-bit OS, shows:

```
MINGW64_NT-10.0-19042 3.1.7-340.x86_64 2021-03-26 22:17 UTC
```

`uname -srv` for my 32-bit OS, shows:

```
MINGW32_NT-6.1-7601 3.1.7-340.i686 2021-03-26 22:01 UTC
```

P.S.: If you'd like to give it a try, this code should work in the program directory, but it doesn't work for me:

```
gunzip -c models/model2/events.gz | code/parser examples/sec23.tagged models/model2/grammar 10000 1 1 1 1 > examples/sec23.model2
```

Comment: Edit your Q to show the output of `uname -srv` . Good luck.

Comment: What terminal emulator are you runing ? WSL (1 or 2 ?) ? CygWin ? Something else ?

Comment: I'm using Git bash. @Aserre

Comment: Tried it with CygWin, and got the same result.

Comment: @Leila cygwin isn't a Linux environment either. Cygwin binaries are native Windows binaries

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As indicated by `file`, your program is a **Linux application** so you can't run it on Windows. See

- [Why does a linux compiled program not work on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32117572/995714)
- [Why won't Windows EXE files work on Linux?](https://superuser.com/q/209703/241386)
- [Why do you need to recompile C/C++ for each OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61644911/995714)

Mingw is **not** an environment for running Linux executables, it's just a compiler that compiles POSIX code into *native Windows binaries*. Neither is Cygwin, which is a reimplementation of POSIX system calls in Windows, and Cygwin binaries are also *native Windows binaries* with a dependency on Cygwin DLLs. Read [this](https://superuser.com/a/626712/241386) if you want to know their differences. Bash is a [shell](https://superuser.com/q/144666/241386) and isn't a platform to execute files either. Only the runtime platform (OS or something like JVM or .NET CLR VM) can run programs and a [shell](https://superuser.com/q/144666/241386) is just a tool to interact with the OS

So you must run Linux programs in a Linux environment like a Linux machine or WSL1/2. Since the program is 32-bit, you can only run it in Linux or [WSL2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58980431/995714)

Since you have the source code you can also compile the code with mingw or cygwin and run on Windows

Comment: That's a thorough explanation and made me realize where the issue lies. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the answer provided by @phuclv, I realized I need to run the program in Linux. So, I installed *32-bit Linux* (I used Linux Mint Debian Edition) on a **virtual machine** (VirtualBox) on my *64-bit Windows 10*, and it worked!

Answer (score 2):

I have ran into same issue on Ubuntu Server and got the following error:

`-bash: /usr/bin/my-script: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`

I found a general solution for running x86-64 files on arm CPU. Running the following code fixed it:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y qemu-user-static binfmt-support
sudo dpkg --add-architecture amd64
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libc6:amd64
```

Source : https://www.kali.org/docs/arm/x86-on-arm/

Comment: the question was tagged [tag:windows] so this doesn't answer it